# WCF binding, contracts, knowntypes

Tags: wcf, msmq

I have been able to do this before with a prototype project but because now it is going into "implementation" with other things included in the project, there are some problems I am having in terms of WCF being able to pick up messages from the MSMQ.

The solution is structured that we have "teams". Each project represents this (to some extent).
Teams can only access the projects they require.

So:

IncomingMessaging project (references "Messages" project)

This contains classes which are concrete classes which derive from base classes of its own type (in "Messages" project). The base classes are all in "Messages" project. Example:

```
FirstReport -> FirstReportBase
SecondReport -> SecondReportBase
ThirdReport -> ThirdReportBase
```

Each of the base classes derive from "MainBase". This also resides in "Messages" project.
The MainBase has been decorated with the KnownTypes attribute and has all the base known types. (FirstReportBase, SecondReportBase etc...)

I then have a WCFImplementation.Messages project, which references "Messages" and the "IncomingMessaging" project.
The WCFImplementation.Messages project has a concrete class which is used for WCF binding to MSMQ the actual implementation like so:

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public class InboundMessagingService : IInboundMessagingService
{
   [OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true)]
   public void ProcessIncomingMessage(MsmqMessage<MainBase> msg) { ... }
}
```

The IInboundMessagingService has the ServiceContract attribute and also has the ServiceKnownType attributes for all the base types

with me so far?

I then have a simple Console app project to host the service. Note at this point I have send a FirstReport message to the queue:

```
FirstReport fr = new FirstReport(....);
```

The console app is run and I get a faulted service. It is unable to read the message on the queue! (poison message)

What am I missing? 
Does the Interface for the IInboundMessagingService have to be decorated with the concrete classes? Can I not just use base classes?

I got it to work with the prototype before as I have both the concrete (FirstReport) and base classes (FirstReportBase) decorated as the service known types in the interface but this was a "loose" type project structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem seemed to have been that the objects and subobjects etc... needed all to be marked with the DataContract attributes.
Then the main concrete/base class should have knowntypes attributes decorated with the known types which are the subclasses of this base class.